# react-native-sound audio is playing but sound not working in android avd how solve this

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, audio, react-native-sound

**react-native-sound**

- tried manual configuration
  https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/Installation
  but sound is not audible.

1. file loaded successfully
2. audio is playing - but volume sound is not hearing in android avd, `
   [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)

Answer (score 0):

To configure the sound on an Android Virtual Device (AVD) so that it plays through the host machine's speakers instead of the virtual device's default sound settings, you can follow these steps:

```
Launch the AVD Manager from within Android Studio by selecting "Tools" > "AVD Manager" from the top menu bar.

Click the "Edit" (pencil) icon for the AVD you wish to configure.

In the AVD configuration window, scroll down to the "Hardware" section and click the "New Hardware Profile" button.

In the "New Hardware Profile" dialog, select "Audio Playback Support" and click the "Add" button.

In the "Audio Playback Support" section, select the "Use Host GPU" checkbox.

Select "Host" from the "Audio Playback Mode" dropdown menu.

Click "Finish" to save the new hardware profile and close the dialog.

Back in the AVD configuration window, select the new hardware profile from the "Hardware Profile" dropdown menu.

Click the "Show Advanced Settings" button.

In the "Advanced Settings" section, enter the following values for the audio settings:

"Audio Backend": "OpenSL ES"
"Channel Count": "Stereo"
"Sample Rate": "44100"

Click "OK" to save the AVD configuration.
```

With these settings, the audio output from the AVD will be routed through the host machine's audio system, allowing you to hear the sound through your computer's speakers or headphones.

Comment: sorry, there is no Audio Playback Support option in New Hardware Profile,

Comment: in react native video - captureAudio={true} is used to capture the audio from video and its worked, when playing the video audio is hearing.
is any props available for react native sound to capture the audio.